# How to ignore softDelete query filter for included entities using a Repository?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I created a DataLayer for my project that uses EfCore5, I configured my DbContext to handle softDelete records:

```
//DbContext    
modelBuilder.Entity<EntityName>().HasQueryFilter(p => !p.Deleted);
```

In my Repository:

```
   // Repository Interface
    public interface IRepository<T,TKey> where T : class
    {
        ICollection<T> FindAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<T>, IIncludableQueryable<T, object>> include = null, bool hideDeleted = true);
    }

   // Repository
   public class Repository<TEntity, TKey> : IRepository<TEntity, TKey> where TEntity : class, IEntity<TKey>
    {
        public ICollection<TEntity> FindAll(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, object>> include = null, bool hideDeleted = true)
        {
            using var db = new TEGVContext();
            IQueryable<TEntity> query = db.Set<TEntity>();
            if (!hideDeleted)
                query = query.IgnoreQueryFilters();

            if (include != null)
                query = hideDeleted ? include(query) : include(query).IgnoreQueryFilters();

            return filter == null
                ? query.ToList()
                : query.Where(filter).ToList();
        }
    }
```

In controller:

```
 var model = _Repo.FindById(id, include: a => a
                        .Include(x => x.Entity2).ThenInclude(l => l.Entity2_1)
                        .Include(x => x.Entity3).ThenInclude(l => l.Entity3_1), false);
```

In my code IgnoreQueryFilters works with the main Entity but not with Include and ThenInclude, the called entities in includes still applies the queryFilter.

How can I make my code be able to ignorequeryfilters on selected includes? And is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Have you registered the query filter for all entitites or only the root one?

Comment: I registered the query filter for all required entities in DbContext like I added above.

Answer (score 1):

`IgnoreQueryFilters` is a query-level option affecting all entities in the query.  There is no option to turn off query filters for only some entities in a query.

And why would you want to write

```
var model = _Repo.FindById(id, include: a => a
                        .Include(x => x.Entity2).ThenInclude(l => l.Entity2_1)
                        .Include(x => x.Entity3).ThenInclude(l => l.Entity3_1), false);
```

instead of the more straightforward

```
var model = _Repo.FindById(id)
                 .IgnoreQueryFilters()
                 .Include(x => x.Entity2).ThenInclude(l => l.Entity2_1)
                 .Include(x => x.Entity3).ThenInclude(l => l.Entity3_1)
                 .ToList();
```

you would get by having your repository wrapper return an IQueryable?  Or the

```
var model = db.Entity1
              .IgnoreQueryFilters()
              .Where(e => e.Id == id)
              .Include(x => x.Entity2).ThenInclude(l => l.Entity2_1)
              .Include(x => x.Entity3).ThenInclude(l => l.Entity3_1)
              .ToList();
```

you get by removing the custom repository wrapper entierly?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your solution is somewhat can be valid, but in my case I didn't want to expose the dbContext to the rest of the projects and decided to use a custom repo. Things were fine till I stumbled in this queryfilter issue and I was wondering if there is a tweak that I can apply to save me from changing the whole project, and it will be a massive change.

Comment: Using a Repo shouldn't matter so long as you're properly composing the criteria into a single query.